# Freelancing Tax implication

Tags: united-states, taxes, online, egypt

Here's my situation.
I'm Egyptian and I have a full-time job in a company which already settles our income tax monthly.
To increase my earnings in my free time, I'm looking to do some freelancing activities for a US-based website noting that I do not have any private freelancing businesses or tax card for that matter.
Do I have any tax implication on the earnings I make through the website?

Comment: By "Egyptian" do you mean a citizen of Egypt, a resident of Egypt, or both?

Answer (score 1):

If you have income in the US, you will owe US income tax on it, unless there is a treaty with your country that says otherwise.

Comment: I think this answer is too vague.  Presumably the poster does not know exactly what it means to "have income in the US".